# Export to PDF with wkhtmltopdf from HTML String

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-generation, jquery-ui-datepicker, wkhtmltopdf

I have a website with HTML/CSS and a JavaScript generated inline datepicker. You can mark days in datepicker.

I want to export the whole content with the marks in datepicker as a PDF.

With Client-Side jsPDF and canvas2html I have a problem with position and sizes. I get partial content in the PDF only (begin or end from datepicker).

Now I try it with wkhtmltopdf.

I get the HTML with $("#datepicker").html() and send it to a PHP Script.
It works with a test string, but I get a blank pdf when I use real data.

```
$.ajax({
  data: 'htmlstring=' + escape($("#datepicker").html()),
  url: 'http://example.com/htmltopdf.php',
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(msg) {
   alert(msg);
  }
});

<?php
  $htmlString = $_POST["htmlstring"];
  //$htmlString = rawurldecode($htmlString);
  exec('echo "<html><head></head><body>' . $htmlString . '</body></html>" | /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --encoding UTF-8 - export.pdf');
?>
```

I also like a different working solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {
   htmlstring: escape($("#datepicker").html())
}
```

Comment: "The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}"